# Why is this example for uploading a file using php not working?

Tags: php, eclipse, macos, xampp

This is example 7-15 (upload.php) from "Learning PHP, MYSQL & JavaScript" by Robin Nixon (5th Ed.):

```
<?php // upload.php
  echo <<<_END
    <html><head><title>PHP Form Upload</title></head><body>
    <form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10'>
    <input type='submit' value='Upload'>
    </form>
_END;

  if ($_FILES)
  {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
    echo "Uploaded image '$name'<br><img src='$name'>";
  }

  echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

I have installed XAMPP on a Mac running OS X 12.2.1.  I changed DirectoryRoot in the file /Application/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf to point to the directory $proj/WebDev.  As recommended by the book, I am using an IDE (Eclipse in my case) for development and testing.  All the exercises in ch. 1-6, and all prior exercises in ch. 7, work both in the Eclipse environment, and by providing the URL directly to the browser (Firefox), such as "localhost/WebDev/upload.php".  The code allows me to locate a jpg file to upload, the Upload button can be pressed, but: (1) there is no 'Uploaded image' message; and (2) the uploaded file is not there.  After execution, "no file selected" appears next to the "Choose File" button.  What am I missing?

Comment: If that's the whole script I don't see where `$name` is set which will be the uploaded files filename.

Answer (score 1):

$name is not initialized. move_uploaded_file does not know where to move file.
Make it like this:

```
<?php // upload.php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
  echo <<<_END
    <html><head><title>PHP Form Upload</title></head><body>
    <form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10'>
    <input type='submit' value='Upload'>
    </form>
_END;

  if ($_FILES && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))
  {
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
    echo "Uploaded image '$name'<br><img src='$name'>";
  }
  echo "</body></html>";
```

If you'd like to learn more add this line as first to check notices, warnings and errors from PHP.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```